# Cross-Recurrence plots in R (with or without ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, data-visualization

I have different time-series corresponding to different individuals and their location within a building (a categorical variable -- more like a room name).

I would like to study the similarity in movement of different individuals by something like cross-recurrence plots, where the two time-series correspond to the two axes and the actual points correspond to the presence/absence of individuals in the same room.

Has anyone tried doing such plots in R or while using ggplot? Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used this routine. I used only d2 dimension and Lyapunov exponent for EEG but this package Tisean (RTisean for your case) has a routine ['recurr'] that returns the specific plot.

This [link](http://www.recurrence-plot.tk/programmes.php) has a nice wrap up of tutorials and links

Edited:

In this [link](https://sites.google.com/site/dynamicsystemsatutah/home/crqa) you can find a nice example of application of recurrence plot.

The return variables of function recur(and similar functions of other packages) you can access after putting $ after the dataset (like database)
and you can access them inside in ggplot function and applying the appropriate aes.

Comment: Thanks! But I see that 'RTisean' package is not available for newest version of R. I also found another package called crqa [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/crqa/index.html) but it does not seem to have a method to generate plots.

Comment: Yes indeed is outdated as I edited my answer there is a script which you can achieve the result that you want. Taking the function crqa and accessing the data from this function and adding them as input to the ggplot function.

Comment: OH! Thats great! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I don't want to spam you but if you are also interested in python data tools, you can check the syncpy and the corresponding function 'cross recurrence '

Comment: That's again a great suggestion! Thanks again :)